# ruby sequel gem - how to query arrays with the pg_array extension

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am using the [pg_array](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array_rb.html) extension and sequel version 4.1.1.

I have added the extension like this:

```
Sequel::Database.extension :pg_array
```

I have created a column like this:

```
alter_table :emails do
  add_column :references, "text[]", null: true
end
```

I can load and retrieve arrays into a postgress array column, just like working with normal arrays.

What is not clear from the above link is how do I execute a query based on the values in this array column.

For example, if one row in the emails table contained these values in the references column:

```
                             references                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 {}
 {5363f773bccf9_32123fe75c45e6f090953@Pauls-MacBook-Pro.local.mail}
```

How can I query the emails table to find a row that contains a references array value of the above value:

```
Email.where(references: ????)
```

Comment: Please put the example here in the post, for which you want help ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit is that clearer?

Comment: Usually you'll want to use operators like `@>` to determine membership, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `pg_array_ops` extension:

```
Sequel.extension :pg_array_ops
Email.where(Sequel.pg_array_op(:references).contains('5363f773bccf9_32123fe75c45e6f090953@Pauls-MacBook-Pro.local.mail'))
```

Comment: Is this answer still up to date?

Comment: @SeanDunford, for my sequel#5.25.0 & psql#11.5 it works

Comment: what is the correct way to make a schema migration for array fields with index?

Comment: Working on Sequel 4, it requires `.contains('{5363f773bccf9_32123fe75c45e6f090953@Pauls-MacBook-Pro.local.mail}')`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
ref = '5363f773bccf9'
emails = Email.arel_table
Email.where( emails[ :references ].matches( "%#{ref}%" ))
```